# Custom object to JSON then back to a custom object?

Tags: javascript, json, object

I've seen very similar questions to this, but I can't quite decide if they was answered clearly - maybe I'm being a bit dense, sorry.

I want to have the convenience (and clarity) of my own object, call it a `CardboardBox()`. It won't contain code, just data. I want to write this to a database and read it back later, but obviously, it is a type `Object()` when it's read back. All I can think of to find out what it used to be is:

1. Have a member variable `type` that I set to CARDBOARD_BOX
2. Instantiate a new `CarbardBox()` and use a function (in the box) to copy the properties of `Object()` to the new `CardboardBox()` object

Is there a better way of doing this? I'm pretty sure I can change the *actual* type.

```
function CardboardBox() { 
  this.type = "CARDBOARD_BOX"
  this.name = "No set";
  this.populate = new function(obj) {
    // populate this object with obj properties 
}

var box = new CarboardBox();  // CarboardBox
box.name = "My Box";
send = JSON.stringyfy(box);   
.
.
.
obj = JSON.parse(send);    // Object

if (obj.type == "CARDBOARD_BOX") {
  savedBox = new CardboardBox();
  savedBox.populate(obj);
}
```

Thanks in advance...
Steve

[edit] My test code.

```
function CardboardBox(n) {
  this.name = n;
}

var box = new CardboardBox("My Box");
send = JSON.stringify(box); // JSON CarboardBox()

obj = JSON.parse(send, function fn(obj) { // Object() returned
  log("OB: "+obj.type);
  return obj.type === 'CardboardBox' ? new CardboardBox(obj) : CardboardBox; 
});     
console.log(obj);
```

Output is:

```
OB: undefined utils.js:40
OB: undefined utils.js:40
function CardboardBox(n) {
    this.name = n;
}
```

Comment: Look at the JSON.parse and JSON.stringify arguments. You can have custom callbacks for each object. `JSON.parse(obj, fn); function fn(obj) { return obj.type === 'a' ? new A(obj) : a; }` I would have written a proper answer if I had the time. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Much appreciated, but I'm a bit more confused now. if I use the function (fn) on my `CardboardBox()` then what is returned from `JSON.parse()` is the constructor for `CarboardBox()`. `obj.type` is always undefined. I think I'm missing something...

Comment: @Steve: You have to set `.type`, and you're not using the arguments correctly (the first argument is not `obj` as suggested). See http://jsfiddle.net/LSUJ9/.

Comment: Why does your test code not set the `type` member? That's why `type` is undefined.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One possible solution is the following:

```
function CardboardBox(n) {
  if(typeof(n) == 'string') {
    //build from name string
    this.name = n;
  } else {
    //build from object
    this.name = n.name;
  }

  //add in this object's "type" in a place
  //that is unlikely to exist in other JSON strings
  this.__type = 'CardboardBox';
}

var box = new CardboardBox("My Box");
send = JSON.stringify(box), // JSON CarboardBox()
obj = JSON.parse(send, function(key, val) {
  //if this is an object, and is CardboardBox
  if(typeof(val) === 'object' && val.__type === 'CardboardBox')
      return new CardboardBox(val);

  return val;

  //or if your object is in a context (like window), and there are many of
  //them that could be in there, you can do:
  //
  //if(typeof(val) === 'object' && context[val.__type])
  //    return new context[val.__type](val);
});


console.log(obj);
```

Basically store the object type in a place you know to look for later on when parsing the json. if you have multiple objects you can instantiate in a single scope the second parse method may be more appropriate. This also will account for objects in the JSON that are *not* `CarboardBox`s.

**Edit** Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uK3ek/6/) of this method in action.

Comment: Yes, that was pretty much my solution. I was just wondering if there was a better way. Wish JavaScript had proper classes. Guess I'll end of with some kind of Java Bean type thing.

Comment: Its not that JavaScript "Doesn't have proper classes" it is that the JSON format doesn't support custom objects. So you have to work around that unfortunately, and as far as I know this (or a variation) is the only way to accomplish it. Even if it is abstracted off using Backbone or some framework, it is just doing something similar to this behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

Overall, you're correct: Javascript doesn't have any built-in way to serialize anything beyond plain objects, so going to and from JSON will not produce a particular class when you deserialize it. So you need to either work out serialization/deserialization yourself, or use a library that provides some support.

I personally like [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/) for this problem, as it handles serializing and deserializing quite well. You define a model class, which include a method to save its data to a server in a serialized form, and a method to deserialize it back to the model. The key design issue here is that deserializing is performed *knowing the model* you're deserializing to:

- you either call `myModel.fetch()` to get data from the server based on the model id, or
- you pass a bunch of new data to the model constructor: `new Model(serializedData)`, or
- you pass an array of data for multiple models to a collection that knows the model type: `new ModelCollection(arrayOfSerializedData)`.

What Backbone doesn't do is deal with type-casting data of an unknown type. When I've dealt with this, I've usually done something similar to @Chad's response, but using an intermediary; you could see this as a proxy model, or as a factory:

```
var classes = {
    CardboardBox: ...,
    AluminumBox: ...
}

function Deserializer(json) {
    // parse if you're actually dealing with a string
    var data = JSON.parse(json),
        // now look for some custom type flag - you'll need to set this yourself
        type = data.type,
        // class lookup, perhaps with a default
        Cls = classes[type] || DefaultType;
    return new Cls(data);
}

var obj = new Deserializer(send);
obj instanceof CardboardBox; // should work
```

This still relies on a custom flag to switch types, though - I'm not sure there's any way around this.

Comment: All excellent answers. Thanks. I may end up writing my own JSON wrapper. If I can't get the objects into the correct classes after de-serialisation, the code is going to  get confusing and/or I'll end up doing extra work on the objects later on.