# How to add methods to a (JSON) object's prototype?

Tags: javascript, json, prototype

Let's say I receive some JSON object from my server, e.g. some data for a Person object:

```
{firstName: "Bjarne", lastName: "Fisk"}
```

Now, I want some methods on top of those data, e.g. for calculating the fullName:

```
fullName: function() { return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName; }
```

So that I can

```
var personData = {firstName: "Bjarne", lastName: "Fisk"};
var person = PROFIT(personData);
person.fullName(); // => "Bjarne Fisk"
```

What I basically would want to do here, is to add a method to the object's prototype. The `fullName()` method is general, so should not be added to the data object itself. Like..:

```
personData.fullName = function() { return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName; }
```

... would cause a lot of redundancy; and arguably "pollute" the data object.

What is the current best-practice way of adding such methods to a simple data object?

**EDIT:**

Slightly off topic, but if the problem above can be solved, it would be possible to do some nice pseudo-`pattern matching` like this:

```
if ( p = Person(data) ) {
   console.log(p.fullName());
} else if ( d = Dog(data) ) {
   console.log("I'm a dog lol. Hear me bark: "+d.bark());
} else {
   throw new Exception("Shitty object");
}
```

`Person` and `Dog` will add the methods if the `data` object has the right attributes. If not, return falsy (ie. data does *not* match/conform).

**BONUS QUESTION:** Does anyone know of a library that either uses or enables this (ie makes it easy)? Is it already a javascript pattern? If so, what is it called; and do you have a link that elaborates? Thanks :)

Comment: Shouldn't you already know what type of object it is when you're retrieving the JSON data? It would certainly be possible to create a basic object construction library that does what you're suggesting, it just seems like detecting the type of object based on the properties is not the best way to go about it..especially since different types can have similarly-named properties. Why not just have a `fromJSON` method or constructor function that simply ignored properties that hadn't been defined by the constructor?

Comment: @MattB : I can imagine parseJson function that takes string and path/protoclass map to assign classes to objects upon constructions.
The _path_ here could be for example JsonPath expression: 
http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/

Comment: Hmm, paths are commonly used by Javascript data-binding frameworks to bind an object property to something in the HTML, but I'm not sure why you'd need to use them for constructing objects since most server-side languages now have the ability to serialize to JSON.

Comment: @MattB: consider this function call `parseJsonPlus(str, {"/*": Person} )`.
In plain English: parse json from `str` and construct each child of the data root using `new Person()` rather than `new Object()`. 

In other words: json + path/class declaration = "classified" and structured data.

Comment: Ah, I get it now. Unfortunately I'm not aware of any libraries that do this (it would of course be possible to write one). I did find this though: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12978933/560114

Comment: If writing such a library, it seems like it might be less work to change the way the server serializes to JSON, for example it could include a `__type` property with every object, that way you wouldn't have to worry with JSONPath expressions on the client-side. Of course then your client-side library wouldn't be as portable.

Comment: The second parameter to JSON.parse is the reviver, which almost could be used for this.  But as far as I know, as it walks the tree, it keeps no context to map those paths.  It's working from the leaves to the root, so can't quite get to this idea.  I just posted a different solution which would let your "classes" themselves express whether they match an object and determine how to deserialize it properly if they do.  But it's less declarative than the approach suggested in these comments.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Assuming your Object comes from some JSON library that parses the server output to generate an Object, it will not in general have anything particular in its prototype ; and two objects generated for different server responses will not share a prototype chain (besides Object.prototype, of course ;) )

If you control all the places where a "Person" is created from JSON, you could do things the other way round : create an "empty" Person object (with a method like fullName in its prototype), and extend it with the object generated from the JSON (using $.extend, _.extend, or something similar).

```
var p = { first : "John", last : "Doe"};

function Person(data) {
   _.extend(this, data);
}

Person.prototype.fullName = function() {
   return this.first + " " + this.last;   
}

console.debug(new Person(p).fullName());
```

Comment: Assuming that the same JavaScript script gets data from different servers, then yes, all objects will inherit from the same prototype (`Object.prototype`).

Answer (score 10):

There is another possibility here.  [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) accepts a second parameter, which is a function used to revive the objects encountered, from the leaf nodes out to the root node.  So if you can recognize your types based on their intrinsic properties, you can construct them in a reviver function.  Here's a very simple example of doing so:

```
var MultiReviver = function(types) {
    // todo: error checking: types must be an array, and each element
    //       must have appropriate `test` and `deserialize` functions
    return function(key, value) {
        var type;
        for (var i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
            type = types[i];
            if (type.test(value)) {
                return type.deserialize(value);
            }
        }
        return value;
    };
};

var Person = function(first, last) {
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
};
Person.prototype.fullName = function() {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
};
Person.prototype.toString = function() {return "Person: " + this.fullName();};
Person.test = function(value) {
    return typeof value.firstName == "string" && 
           typeof value.lastName == "string";
};
Person.deserialize = function(obj) {
    return new Person(obj.firstName, obj.lastName);
};

var Dog = function(breed, name) {
    this.breed = breed;
    this.name = name;
}
Dog.prototype.species = "canine";
Dog.prototype.toString = function() {
    return this.breed + " named " + this.name;
};
Dog.test = function(value) {return value.species === "canine";};
Dog.deserialize = function(obj) {return new Dog(obj.breed, obj.name);};


var reviver = new MultiReviver([Person, Dog]);

var text = '[{"firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe"},' +
            '{"firstName": "Jane", "lastName": "Doe"},' +
            '{"firstName": "Junior", "lastName": "Doe"},' +
            '{"species": "canine", "breed": "Poodle", "name": "Puzzle"},' +
            '{"species": "canine", "breed": "Wolfhound", "name": "BJ"}]';

var family = JSON.parse(text, reviver)
family.join("\n");

// Person: John Doe
// Person: Jane Doe
// Person: Junior Doe
// Poodle named Puzzle
// Wolfhound named BJ
```

This depends on you being able to unambiguously recognizing your types.  For instance, if there were some other type, even a subtype of Person, which also had firstName and lastName properties, this would not work.  But it might cover some needs.

Answer (score 5):

If you're dealing with plain JSON data then the prototype of each person object would simply be `Object.prototype`. In order to make it into an object with a prototype of `Person.prototype` you'd first of all need a `Person` constructor and prototype (assuming you're doing Javascript OOP in the traditional way):

```
function Person() {
    this.firstName = null;
    this.lastName = null;
}
Person.prototype.fullName = function() { return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName; }
```

Then you'd need a way to turn a plain object into a Person object, e.g. if you had a function called `mixin` which simply copied all properties from one object to another, you could do this:

```
//example JSON object
var jsonPerson = {firstName: "Bjarne", lastName: "Fisk"};

var person = new Person();
mixin(person, jsonPerson);
```

This is just one way of solving the problem but should hopefully give you some ideas.

---

Update: Now that `Object.assign()` is available in modern browsers, you could use that instead of writing your own mixin function. There's also a shim to make `Object.assign()` work on older browsers; see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill.

Comment: This does exactly what I want. The only problem is that it's kind of cumbersome. I'd imagine there being an even easier way to do this. This has **got** to be a common problem. Is this one of the (many) shortcomings of javascript?

Comment: It could be made less cumbersome if you had a base Model or Entity class that Person and all your other domain model classes inherited from. That base Model class could have a factory method (e.g. `Model.prototype.new`) that accepted a JSON object and did the same thing as my `mixin` example. Or you could use a framework that already includes this type of behavior, e.g. the `Model.init` method of Can.js: http://canjs.us/#can_model-init

Comment: Also, the `Person` constructor could be made slightly more concise by using the `mixin` function, e.g.:

`function Person() {
  mixin(this, {
   firstName: null,
   lastName: null
  });
 }`

Comment: Thanks Matt :)   Can.js looks interesting. Will check it out.

Comment: FYI, there is now a standard method `Object.setPrototypeOf()` that could be used as an alternative solution for this.

Answer (score 4):

You should probably not do this.

JSON allows you to serialize a state, not a type. So in your use case, you should do something like this :

```
var Person = function ( data ) {
    if ( data ) {
        this.firstName = data.firstName;
        this.lastName = data.lastName;
    }
};

Person.prototype.fullName = function ( ) {
    return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
};

//

var input = '{"firstName":"john", "lastName":"Doe"}';
var myData = JSON.parse( input );
var person = new Person( myData );
```

Comment: This is a nice variation on my answer; our answers could also be combined so you used a `mixin` function from within the Person constructor.

Answer (score 3):

In other words you want to change prototype (a.k.a. class) of existing object.
Technically you can do it this way:

```
var Person = {
  function fullName() { return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName; }
};

// that is your PROFIT function body: 
personData.__proto__ = Person ;
```

After that if you will get `true` on `personData instanceof Person`

Comment: You should mention that `__proto__` is non-standard and deprecated in most browsers.

Comment: `__proto__` is non-standard and won't work in certain old browsers; however, it's the only way of changing the prototype of an existing object. This is an interesting answer...and it could be made compatible with all browsers by having a `setPrototype` function that falls back to just copying all methods in browsers that don't support `__proto__`. However this approach might seem a little weird to anyone working on your code without a strong Javascript background.

Comment: @Felix Kling: Yes, `__proto__` may not be supported by IE (didn't check it recently). By my answer I just tried to formalize the requirement - _technically_ (read ideally) that is exactly what the asker need. Particular implementation may vary.

Comment: This works in IE10 and seems the best way to do what the OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

Use the new-ish [Object.setPrototypeOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf).  (It is supported by IE11 and all the other browsers now.)

You could create a class/prototype that included the methods you want, such as your fullName(), and then

```
Object.setPrototypeOf( personData, Person.prototype );
```

As the warning (on MDN page linked above) suggests, this function is not to be used lightly, but that makes sense when you are changing the prototype of an existing object, and that is what you seem to be after.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is common to transport methods with data, but it seems like a great idea.

This project allows you to encode the functions along with your data, but it is not considered standard, and requires decoding with the same library of course.

```
https://github.com/josipk/json-plus
```

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous objects don't have a prototype.  Why not just have this:

```
function fullName(obj) {
    return obj.firstName + ' ' + obj.lastName;
}

fullName(person);
```

If you absolutely must use a method call instead of a function call, you can always do something similar, but with an object.

```
var Person = function (person) { this.person = person; }
Person.prototype.fullName = function () {
    return this.person.firstName + ' ' + this.person.lastName;
}
var person = new Person(personData);
person.fullName();
```

Comment: `function fullName(obj) { return obj.firstName + ' ' + obj.lastName; }` is very un-OOP. Your second solution will make `.firstName` break.

Comment: Just because something uses objects doesn't make it object oriented. Is something "un-OOP" inferior?  "OOP" has destroyed a generation of programmers...  I don't know what you mean by making .firstName break

Comment: He means that in your second example, after the line `var person = new Person(personData);` `person.firstName` would no longer work. It's better to set all the properties as properties of `this` within the Person constructor, that way it behaves like a normal object....the proxy approach complicates the whole thing.

Comment: @MattB but you still have access to the personData object

Comment: @ExplosionPills: I think that it is inferior, yes. The method `fullName` is no longer *transparently* a part of the object's interface. If the person-object is to be passed to some other method in another module, the `fullName` function is not passed along with it, which complicates things :(

Comment: @kornfridge true, it depends on the context in which it's being used. FullName may exist in the other module as well depending on the scope it's defined in. I'm just saying that you don't need to over-complicate things prematurely

Comment: @ExplosionPills: true. I guess my life would be easier if I just did it the `function fullName(obj) { return obj.firstName + ' ' + obj.lastName; }`-way. But the overall feel of it is inelegant, "hacky" and counter-intuitive. Having played with Scala recently, javascript feels incomplete, inconsistent and underdeveloped; it really disgusts me as a TCS-student, that js in its current form continues to be industry standard. :[  The web is an important platform -- it deserves better!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use prototypes in order to bind a custom method in your barebone object.

Here you have an elegant example that don't pollute your code avoiding redundant code

```
var myobj = {
  title: 'example',
  assets: 
  {
    resources: ['zero', 'one', 'two']
  }
}

var myfunc = function(index)
{
    console.log(this.resources[index]); 
}

myobj.assets.giveme = myfunc

myobj.assets.giveme(1);
```

Example available in https://jsfiddle.net/bmde6L0r/