# JSON objects and Javascript Objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am creating front-end of a web app. I am receiving all the responses in JSON, parsing it and putting it as html. I had a look at few javascript MVC frameworks (i.e backbone.js, ember.js etc) and found that they were just overkill for my simple app. But what I found really fascinating is that they all had Models. *I figured out I can create javascript objects and they will be similar to models and as I dont have such complex needs my custom javascript objects shall be easy to make.*

```
function displayCar() {
  var result = "A Beautiful " + this.year + " " + this.make
    + " " + this.model;
  pretty_print(result);
}

function Car(make, model, year, owner) {
  this.make = make;
  this.model = model;
  this.year = year;
  this.owner = owner;
  this.displayCar = displayCar;
}
```

I receive the cars as JSON response from the server. *SO what would be the ideal way : To create the objects while looping over the JSON array OR should I just use the parsing and directly show html from there?*

**Now my question is should I parse the JSON into javascript objects? I am also not sure if using this kind of objects would be much helpful?** *I would also like to know if there is a way to create custom pre-defined objects straight from JSON, as I feel than it might be useful like I want to car objects*

Comment: You will have to extract the data from the JSON one way or the other. So you might as well use a JSON parser (perhaps the built in `JSON.parse()` on modern browsers).

Comment: This may be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15054678/how-to-add-methods-to-a-json-objects-prototype

Comment: @MattGreer I understand that I need to parse it using JSON.parse(). But my question is not that. I am making a edit to the question to explain the question better

Answer (score 1):

Most modern javascript frameworks (jquery, angular, knockout, etc.) will parse the string representation to objects for you, it's not a step you need to worry about.

You don't need to pre-define anything, javascript is a loosely typed language - class definitions are not required.  Essentially a JSON object is a big dictionary of property names to values, your web framework is responsible for serializing the server-side object into a JSON-compatible representation.

With regards to when you need to display the return data, I think that depends on the application you are building.  If you need access to the cars indefinitely, then it may make sense to iterate over them and add methods as required, if however, you just want to display the data, do it when you receive it.

All this is to say, just return your objects from the server, and access the object and properties directly.

This is a method in the controller class, that responds to a URL (pseudo code)

```
public class Car { 
 string make;
 string model;
 string year;
 string owner;
}   

[Get("http://server/cars")]
public Car[] getCars()
{
  // the repository returns an array of Car objects, which in turn are returned to the client
  return myCarRepository.List(0, 25); // always page lists
}
```

Then on the client

```
jQuery
 .get("/server/cars")
 .success(function(carArray) {
    // carArray is an array of car objects that has been deserialized by jquery
    // you can access the properties using dot syntax
   console.log("server returned " + carArray.length + " cars");
   for (var i = 0; i < carArray.length; i++) {
     console.log("car[" + i + "].make = " + carArray[i].make);
     carArray[i].print = displayCar; // if you want to hold on to the array, and display info later, each object in the array has a print() method
   }
  });
```

Comment: `displayCar` isn't a string, it's a Javascript function defined in the question. So it's not part of the JSON.

Comment: Yeah I have understood what you are trying to say. But my problem is if I have a javascript object defined already as I want to have some methods to it, so how would i parse this json array into those objects.

Comment: i would just add the methods to the data returned by the server, and use them when it's appropriate.

Comment: Won't adding such methods to the data returned...be equal to initialising javascript objects using the loop like you have done to add the method.

Comment: Yes, you need to loop over the collection to add the methods.  It may add an extra iteration, but, unless it's a huge collection it won't be too big an operation.  Basically you either have to attach methods to objects and call them or create methods that operate on objects, in either case you will need to find the relevant object to manipulate.  The application you are building will dictate the best strategy to choose - it's situational, I don't think there is ONE BEST WAY

Answer (score 1):

I make some assumtions to answer your questions. Please tell me if any is wrong and i will edit the question accordingliy.

#### Question

> I receive the cars as JSON response from the server. SO what would be the ideal way : To create the objects while looping over the JSON array OR should I just use the parsing and directly show html from there?

#### Answer

If you want to add some methods to each object on the array, you need those predefined "class".

#### Question

> should I parse the JSON into javascript objects?

#### Answer

You will have to parse the JSON into a javascript Object just to use the data.

#### Question

> Using this kind of objects would be much helpful?

#### Answer

If you are refering to Javascript objects, they are really useful and flexible. You can directly use the properties defined on the JSON from the Javascript object after it's parsed.

Suposse an array of Objects taken from JSON, as follows:

```
JSON_ARRAY = [
  {
    "make": "ACME inc",
    "model": "road runner 9999",
    "year": "the future",
    "owner": "nobody"
  },
  // more cars here...
]
```

you could access each car through `JSON_ARRAY[n]`, where `n` is the index of the car in the array.

you could also add your `displayCar` method to each object on the `JSON_ARRAY`

```
for (var i = 0; i < JSON_ARRAY.length; i++) {
    JSON_ARRAY.displayCar = displayCar;
}
```

#### Question

> I would also like to know if there is a way to create custom pre-defined objects straight from JSON, as I feel than it might be useful like I want to car objects.

#### Answer

No, there isn't a way to pre-define a "class" from JSON. You can define a class designed to adapt to a JSON representation of itself, if you want.

```
function Car( car_json ) {
  this.make = car_json.make;
  this.model = car_json.model;
  this.year = car_json.year;
  this.owner = car_json.owner;
}

Car.prototype.displayCar = function() {
   // stuff
}
```

or even better:

```
function Car( json_data ) {
  for( var property in json_data ) {
      this[ property ] = json_data[ property ];
  }
}
```

Anyway, you will have to map the array of objects to an array of Cars:

```
var cars = JSON_CARS_ARRAY.map(function jsonToCar( json ) {
  return new Car( json );
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was really helpful except for one tit bit, should I create separate javascript objects or just parse the JSON response and use that array and its objects as it is without creating a javascript object already predefined.

Comment: And to the answer you have written for map arrays to array of cars. Can't I have an Javascript array and in its initialisation create javascript objects.

Comment: The key is the javascript array is initialized right on the JSON parsing (if using the built in JSON.parse). You surely don't want to write a JSON parsing function to initialize the cars as cars, so it's better, or at least quicker and easier, to alter the JSON outputed array mapping it to a Car Array.

Comment: @SaranshMohapatra If you want to add some methods you need to create the *predefined javascript object* or, bad said, "class". If you are going to use only a display method, you could write it as a function which reads the raw object and puts the output where it's desired.