# JavaScript arguments object does not have all parameters

Tags: javascript, arguments

### Background

I am learning how the `arguments` object works inside a function. I noticed that in theory, this object will have all the arguments passed to the function.

In practice I have quite different results.

### Code

The following code is a test function, that prints the arguments it receives:

```
function test(myArgs){
    console.log(`myArgs: ${myArgs}`);
    console.log(`arguments obj: ${JSON.stringify(arguments)}`);
    console.log(`arguments array ${JSON.stringify(Array.from(arguments))}`);
}
```

the first line prints `myArgs` and the other two print the `arguments` object in a couple different ways.

Executing the function with something simple it works:

```
test("hello", 56, 60, 5);

myArgs: hello
arguments obj: {"0":"hello","1":56,"2":60,"3":5}
arguments array ["hello",56,60,5]
```

### Problem

The problem comes when I pass a function as one of the arguments, like, lets say, a callback:

```
test("hello", () => console.log("HelloWorld"), 60, 5);

myArgs: hello
arguments obj: {"0":"hello","2":60,"3":5}
arguments array ["hello",null,60,5]
```

This is quite unexpected ...

### Code

Following is a snippet that exemplifies this behavior:

```js
    function test(myArgs){
     console.log(`myArgs: ${myArgs}`);
     console.log(`arguments obj: ${JSON.stringify(arguments)}`);
     console.log(`arguments array ${JSON.stringify(Array.from(arguments))}`);
    }

test("hello", 56, 60, 5);
test("hello", () => console.log("HelloWorld"), 60, 5);
```

### Questions

1. Why doesn't this work?
2. How can I access a function if I have multiple arguments ?

Comment: JSON cannot contain functions as values, so you end up with `null`.

Comment: Also note that the `arguments` object is more or less deprecated in modern JavaScript.

Comment: console.log doesn't require you to JSON.stringify objects. It'll stringify them for you in a human readable way

Comment: To add to Pointy's comment, the spread operator is now the accepted way to access variadic parameters. (...myArgs) => console.log(...myArgs);

Comment: @Pointy actually, I think `JSON.stringify(fn)` returns `undefined` but in the context of a container, that gets converted to `null`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [json.stringify does not process object methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18089033/json-stringify-does-not-process-object-methods)

Comment: @canon sure, that's possible; the point is that it's not the function :)

Comment: When I first created this post my focus was on Functions, not objects. So I object to it being a dup. Thanks for answer and directions !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `JSON.stringify()` doesn't serialize functions.

... but it can. Provide a custom [`replacer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_replacer_parameter) callback and handle serialization of functions yourself:

```js
var values = [1, false, {foo:2}, function bar() {}];

console.log(JSON.stringify(values, function(key, value) {
  if ("function" === typeof value) {
    return value.toString();
  }
  return value;
}));
```

<sub>See `Function.prototype.toString()` and `JSON.stringify(value, replacer)`.</sub>