# JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object_with_function)) is undefined

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({func: function(){alert(1);}})).func
```

I JSON.parse a JSON.stringify object (that contained a function), but the result was undefined. Why is this?

Comment: The condition will return `false` even if you strip out the `JSON.stringify` and  `JSON.parse`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/9817706/4636715 for comparing functions.

Comment: Two individual objects are never equal to each other: `console.log({} === {})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18089033/json-stringify-does-not-process-object-methods).

> JSON.stringify() will encode values that JSON supports. Objects with
>   values that can be objects, arrays, strings, numbers and booleans.
>   Anything else will be ignored or throw errors. Functions are not a
>   supported entity in JSON. JSON handles pure data only, functions are
>   not data, but behavior with more complex semantics.

This means that using JSON.parse(JSON.stringify()) on a object with methods will not be equal to the object that hasn't been stringified.

Answer (score 3):

> JSON.stringify() will encode values that JSON supports. Objects with
>   values that can be objects, arrays, strings, numbers and booleans.
>   Anything else will be ignored or throw errors. Functions are not a
>   supported entity in JSON. JSON handles pure data only, functions are
>   not data, but behaviour with more complex semantics.

So, basically you need your own reducer and parsers while stringifying and parsing object and that can be done as:

```js
var myObject = {
        num: 50,
        str: 'A string here',
        today: new Date(),
        ar: ['one', 'two', 'three'],
        myFunction: function(val) {
            console.log(val);
        }
    }

    // example replacer function
    function replacer(name, val) {
        // convert RegExp or function to string
        if ( val && val.constructor === Function) {
            return val.toString();
        } else {
            return val; // return as is
        }
    };

    // example replacer function
    function parser(name, val) {
        if ( val && typeof val == "string" && val.startsWith("function")){
            return new Function('return ' + val)();
        } else {
            return val; // return as is
        }
    };
    var jsonObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myObject, replacer), parser);

    //because of different reference , this will evaluate to false
    console.log(myObject.myFunction == jsonObject.myFunction);
    //true because of same content
    console.log(myObject.myFunction.toString() == jsonObject.myFunction.toString());
    //evaluate same as same function
    console.log(myObject.myFunction(5) == jsonObject.myFunction(5));
```

Answer (score 1):

Because Object is a reference type, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify()) returns a new Object, and the == expression compares their address when comparing reference types, so it returns false.

Comment: I think you mean "object" instead of "function".

Comment: You won't get a different fiunction. You cannot get a function object from JSON at all, since JSON does not support functions.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to your question can be demonstrated as:

```js
console.log({} == {});

var example = {};
var test = example;
console.log(example == test);
```

In the first case, we are comparing 2 new empty Objects. Each Object has its own allocation in memory, and so when comparing reference types, this is what is compared. Therefore, `false` is returned as they are not the same.

In the second example, we "point" a new variable (`test`) to an existing Object (`example`). Here we see that it returns `true` because this time we are comparing the same memory allocation.

Comment: look at this instead i had a misleading example alert(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({func: function(){alert(1);}})).func);

Comment: @JasonC. functions can not be stringified.